# Create cabinet in trash compactor space

Tags: framing, cabinets

I removed my trash compactor and I want to use that space as cabinet. I want to install cabinet door. But before I do that, I need to attach top and bottom face frames where red lines are in picture.

How can I join new pieces of face frames with existing verical piece ? Can I use wood glue ?

[image]
enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: Consider a roll-out/pull-out shelf here. Trash compactor footprint is narrow and deep - making effective use of the space would be easier (IMHO) with a pull out shelf you can get to the back of easily from the sides with it pulled out, rather than a deep narrow cabinet where things get lost at the back corners.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly hard to answer without knowing what tools you have at your disposal. Perfect world, you'd have access to a complete shop (tablesaw, chopsaw, pneumatics, pocket hole jig). My description will talk about tools I'd use. Imperfect world, you can usually fake it with hand tools.

You probably want a well-supported shelf at the bottom. I'd cut it so that it would be a very tight friction fit. I'd support it on 4 sides, direct to the floor. The front support can be a surrogate for a toe kick panel. (Supports can be anywhere from 3/4" thick on up.)

The top and bottom rails can be glue only, but better if you pocket screw them into the stiles. Definitely glue the bottom rail to the shelf. I'd air nail the rail to the front of the shelf as well. You could put something as a backer for the top rail as well, but those parts don't get anywhere near the abuse that a bottom rail gets.

Answer (score 1):

To just install the face frame part of the cabinet, you could use some  inside corner supports along with some glue. The supports would be mounted to the inside and use screw short enough so they don't break through the outside finished surface.

[image]

If you're installing a toe kick, you can screw the lower face frame to it from the inside.